# XML Specific Parsing in Python

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I am trying to do some XML parsing with Python but I am getting stuck and I seem to find no example. Let's say I have an XML like this:

```
<entries>
 <companies>
   <company>
  <name>ACME</name>
    <size>50000</size>
    <location>USA</location>
   </company>
   <company>
  <name>PROGNET</name>
   <size>3039</size>
   <location>Mexico</location>
  </company>
 </companies>
</entries>
```

I want to be able to print all inside 
(basically I don't want to see `<entries>` and `</entries>`)

How can I achieve that ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are [xml parsing packages](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html) that can help you do that.

Comment: I have tried reading all that documentation, tried almost everything I found in the documentation, but with no success. I'm getting stuck with this.

Comment: I uploaded an example as another answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to print the content using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Notice this is a recursive solution, so it won't work for very deep xml files.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def travel_xml(xml_node):
    for child in xml_node:
        txt = child.text.strip()  # remove whitespaces
        if txt != "":
            print txt
        travel_xml(child)

tree = ET.parse('your_xml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
travel_xml(root)
```

The output would be:

```
ACME
50000
USA
PROGNET
3039
Mexico

Process finished with exit code 0
```